# Question about traffic simulation

Tags: support, scope, site-recommendation

Is StackOverflow the correct section for a question about the traffic studies? The question is related to the motorway.

I am thinking to 2 cars getting into motorway they are travelling between 80 and 130 km/h. When raising the number of cars the average speed should stay 80 km/h except for 5 second that is the time needed for "syncing" (avoid crashing) when a new car enters the motorway. The average speed should not be so much influenced by the new cars entering the motorway.

So the question become: why raising the number of cars happens a phenomenon, commonly called traffic, which can lower the average speed to 0 km/h?

I think the problem happens when the syncing between cars in the motorway and the car who want to enter takes too much time.

But I would like to look for scientific studies about that.

Comment: Sounds more like a stats question.  Your question has a chance of being on-topic at [Cross-Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) (please read the on-topic for that site before posting).

Comment: This question doesn't appear to have any relationship to the scope of Stack Overflow, which specializes in programming-related questions. Asking for a scientific explanation for motor-vehicle traffic behavior is not related to programming. (If you were writing a simulation and encountered a specific bug that broke your simulation, that would be on-topic.) If you wish to ask general site-recommendation questions, you may do so on http://meta.stackexchange.com. Site-rec questions on Meta.SO should have some relationship to programming or computers.

Comment: @apsillers:  That really should be the answer to this question.

Comment: +1 Thanks for asking whether or not it was on-topic rather than just posting.

Comment: Model it like economics. There is a certain supply of space available on the road. When there are too many people the demand for that space exceeds the supply. #traffic

Comment: @Makoto: Probably you are right but I am also question banned on meta.stackoverflow.. so I thought to post it here even if it's not the perfect place. But yes, that's would be a correct answer, even if not the best, since it would not be useful and it would not really change so much to have it her or on meta.. imho of course

Comment: But one question.. I've been question banned on meta.stackexchange because my questions with the tag discussion where not well received by the community. I wrote about things which made people become very emotional and I got 20 downvotes. Do you think usefult that I cannot open neither questions with the tag "bug" or "support"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is some kind of math/science theory question and is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Questions regarding a specific software implementation of say a simulation could be on-topic.